# Android webview doesn't finish rendering text

Tags: android, text, webview, render

I'm developing an application that requires somewhat complex html rendering (basically text and images, but the text may have some advanced features like custom font and path) and I'm using webviews to render the content.

The problem is that some of the pages doesn't render text in some devices.

I'm using all three callbacks:

- onPageFinished;
- onProgressChanged;
- onNewPicture (deprecated, but some users related that it works)

but even if they're triggered I get a WebView that is missing the text in most of the pages. On some devices when I touch the webview the text appears, but it's an erratic behaviour that can't be trusted.

I also tried called invalidate() constantly but it doesn't force the text to draw. I'm logging the webview console and apparently it's not throwing any error (notice that sometimes the text is rendered perfectly and the problem occurs for pages that rendered correctly before). I'm configuring my webview like (I know that some methods are deprecated, but some other solutions related that it worked for then):

```
offScreenWebView.layout(0, 0, viewPortWidth, viewPortHeight);
offScreenWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
offScreenWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
offScreenWebView.getSettings().setTextZoom(100);
offScreenWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
offScreenWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
offScreenWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
offScreenWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    offScreenWebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
}
```

I'm at loose now, because I've no clue why the text doesn't render and it seems I can't force it to render.

Comment: I've detected that the pages in which the text doesn't appear the onProgressChanged is stuck at 90.

Comment: I've worked some kinks during the day and I've found that if I remove the custom fonts the problem doesn't occur, but I need to render with custom fonts because the page layout depends on them.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to somewhat solve my problem. The main issue I was having was due to the webviews were being loaded simultaneously (they're used at a viewpager) and probably this incurred in some concurrency problem when the webviews were loading the font. I encapsulated the URL loading and ensured that the webviews were loaded one page at a time.

Also, when destroying the webviews I couldn't call any method like cancelTimer, this resulted in problems when rendering other pages with similar font. The only thing I did was to point the references to null.

It's somewhat slow but at least it was the only way to get consistent rendering results using the webviews.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the latest update to Android System Web View, that comes automatically from Google Play. If you uninstall the update, it helps. It is of course not a really good solution((((
Another workaround is disable HW accelleration in the webview